# Existence of a finite measure

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

Let $\mu_1, \dots , \mu_n$ be finite measures on $(X,\Sigma)$. Then there is a finite measure $\mu$ on $(X,\Sigma)$ such that for every $\varepsilon>0$ there are disjoint sets $S_1, \dots , S_N \in \Sigma$ such that for $i=1,\dots,n$ we have

$$ \mu_i = \sum_{j=1}^N \alpha_{i,j} \mu_{S_j} + \kappa_i$$

where $\alpha_{k,j}\in [0,\infty)$ and $\kappa_1, \dots , \kappa_n$ are measures such that

$$\kappa_1(X) + \dots + \kappa_n(X) < \varepsilon.$$

If $S\in\Sigma$ and $\mu$ is a measure, then by $\mu_S$ we mean the restriction of $\mu$ to S, that is, $\mu_S(A)=\mu(A \cap S)$.

I have a hard time with this question, I only need a hint or a sketch of  the proof.